# Input Problems in RUST

Tags: rust

mismatched types
expected enum `Result<(i32, i32), ScanError>`
found enum `Option<_>`
i keep getting this error in this Code:

```
use scan_fmt::scan_fmt;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Error while reading input");

    if let Some((n1, d1)) = scan_fmt!(&input, "{}/{}", i32, i32) {
        // Trim the newline character from parsed values
        let n1 = n1.trim();
        let d1 = d1.trim();
        println!("Input taken successfully: {}/{}", n1, d1);
    } else {
        println!("Format mismatched...");
    }

    input.clear();  // Clear the input
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Error while reading input");

    if let Some((n2, d2)) = scan_fmt!(&input, "{}/{}", i32, i32) {
        // Trim the newline character from parsed values
        let n2 = n2.trim();
        let d2 = d2.trim();
        println!("Input taken successfully: {}/{}", n2, d2);
    } else {
        println!("Format mismatched...");
    }
}
```

i tried taking 2 inouts from a single readline but it is not working

Comment: Not sure what’s confusing. Looking at the docs, scan_fat gives you a Result and you’re doing pattern match with an Option. You need `if let Ok(…)`.

Comment: Are you looking for `scan_fmt_some!`?

Comment: It seems `scan_fmt_some!` unwraps the values without an `Option` or `Result`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ok()` on a `Result<T, _>` to convert it into an `Option<T>`.

e.g.

```
use scan_fmt::scan_fmt;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Error while reading input");

    if let Some((n1, d1)) = scan_fmt!(&input, "{}/{}", i32, i32).ok() {
        // Trim the newline character from parsed values
        let n1 = n1;
        let d1 = d1;
        println!("Input taken successfully: {}/{}", n1, d1);
    } else {
        println!("Format mismatched...");
    }

    input.clear();  // Clear the input
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Error while reading input");

    if let Some((n2, d2)) = scan_fmt!(&input, "{}/{}", i32, i32).ok() {
        // Trim the newline character from parsed values
        let n2 = n2;
        let d2 = d2;
        println!("Input taken successfully: {}/{}", n2, d2);
    } else {
        println!("Format mismatched...");
    }
}
```

Without calling `ok()` it is up to you to change the matching expression of your `if let` to `Ok(...)`

e.g.

```
use scan_fmt::scan_fmt;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Error while reading input");

    if let Ok((n1, d1)) = scan_fmt!(&input, "{}/{}", i32, i32) {
        // Trim the newline character from parsed values
        let n1 = n1;
        let d1 = d1;
        println!("Input taken successfully: {}/{}", n1, d1);
    } else {
        println!("Format mismatched...");
    }

    input.clear();  // Clear the input
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Error while reading input");

    if let Ok((n2, d2)) = scan_fmt!(&input, "{}/{}", i32, i32) {
        // Trim the newline character from parsed values
        let n2 = n2;
        let d2 = d2;
        println!("Input taken successfully: {}/{}", n2, d2);
    } else {
        println!("Format mismatched...");
    }
}
```

The latter is the better option, since you can handle the error of the result, the first will just convert any error to `None`.